# Fading effect everytime I add an item in my table ein javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a webapp using ASP.NET, C# and jQuery. And I have a page where I add a certain item. And in this item, it will also list all the current items. Above the list is a form that I can add a new Item. Then everytime I add a new item will add above of list with a fading effect. Is this possible?

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/02/simple-effects-plugins

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you have the new record in a `tr` row you could do something like this:

```
$tr = newRow(); //Create tr with your new record here
$tr.hide();
$tr.appendTo($("#your_table")).fadeIn();
```

Hope this helps